# Random Initialisation of Hidden State of LSTM in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I used a model for my music generation project. The model is created as follows

```
        self.model.add(LSTM(self.hidden_size, input_shape=(self.input_length,self.notes_classes),return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=dropout) ,)
        self.model.add(LSTM(self.hidden_size,recurrent_dropout=dropout,return_sequences=True))
        self.model.add(LSTM(self.hidden_size,return_sequences=True))
        self.model.add(BatchNorm())
        self.model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.model.add(Dense(256))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(BatchNorm())
        self.model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        self.model.add(Dense(256))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(BatchNorm())
        self.model.add(Dense(self.notes_classes))
        self.model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

After Training this model with 70% accuracy, Whenever I generate music, it always gives same kind of starting notes with little variation for whatever the input notes. I think it is possible to solve this condition by initialising the hidden state of the LSTM, at the start of the generation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two states, the `state_h` which is the last step output; and the `state_c` which is the carry on state or memory.

You should use a functional API model to have more than one input:

```
main_input = Input((self.input_length,self.notes_classes))
state_h_input = Input((self.hidden_size,))
state_c_input = Input((self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size))

out = LSTM(self.hidden_size, return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=dropout,
           initial_state=[state_h_input, state_c_input])(main_input)

#I'm not changing the following layers, they should have their own states if you want to

out = LSTM(self.hidden_size,recurrent_dropout=dropout,return_sequences=True)(out)
out = LSTM(self.hidden_size,return_sequences=True)(out)
out = BatchNorm()(out)
out = Dropout(dropout)(out)
out = Dense(256)(out)
out = Activation('relu')(out)
out = BatchNorm()(out)
out = Dropout(dropout)(out)
out = Dense(256)(out)
out = Activation('relu')(out)
out = BatchNorm()(out)
out = Dense(self.notes_classes)(out)
out = Activation('softmax')(out)

self.model = Model([main_input, state_h_input, state_c_input], out)
```

Following this approach, it's even possible to use outputs of other layers as initial states, if you want trainable initial states.

The big change is that you will need to pass the states for training and predicting:

```
model.fit([original_inputs, state_h_data, state_c_data], y_train)
```

Where you can use zeros for the states during training.

Comment: So in your solution for my case I only need to change state_c_input to some random matrix of its shape. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, maybe H too. I'm just not entirely sure the shapes for these states are correct in my answer. (If they're not correct you'll get an error and then we can talk more :p)

Comment: How can find the shape